# Why are NSLogs in Xcode 8 cut off?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, logging, nslog

I just installed Xcode 8 and I use NSLogs to see my server response and for other verifications.
However, my NSLogs with my server response (in JSON) are getting cut off.
Any Ideas?
I am using objective-c and running my app on a real device.

Comment: you mean you can't see full response ? Can you post the response you get ?

Comment: Yeah I cant view the full response. You can view my full response [link](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=4ca561ab37dfcfd536d1a652d4ffdd06)

Comment: On line 84 on the left side on the JSON online editor you will see this line: "name": "Equipment",but in the logs it gets cuf off after "name": "Equi

Comment: In PostMan all my data is there and is also being parsed correctly in the app.

Comment: try `printf` instead of `NSLog` like: `printf("%s", [string UTF8String]);`

Comment: That doesn't work for objects. My data changes and has arrays and dictionaries. I also like NSLogs for the extra info it gives

Comment: @bryannorden did you fix this? I am facing the same problem and I don't know how to solve it

Comment: @antonio__ check out my answer I posted. Its due to a iOS 10 bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to figure this out with the help of [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584707/nslog-on-devices-in-ios-10-xcode-8-seems-to-truncate-why%5D)

You have to create a global header (YourProjectName.pch) Then post this line:

```
 #define NSLog(FORMAT, ...) printf("%s\n", [[NSString stringWithFormat:FORMAT, ##__VA_ARGS__] UTF8String]);
```

Then you can call NSLog like normal from any view like NSLog(@"My array data: %@", anArray);